# How to get a value from loop in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Three items present in orderDetail when I run the code every product show three radio buttons. How to get each product radio button value after click or change any radio button?

```html
<div class="order-items-detail" *ngFor="let data of orderDetails.response.orderItems">
    <div class="p-field-radiobutton">
        <p-radioButton [(ngModel)]="data.item.picked" 
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            value="Picked"
            class="radio-menter code hereargin"
            name="radioStatus" 
        ></p-radioButton>
        <br />
        <p-radioButton [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
            [(ngModel)]="data.item.unavaliable"
            value="Unavailable"
            class="radio-margin"
            name="radioStatus"
        ></p-radioButton>
        <p-radioButton [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            value="Substitute"
            class="radio-margin"
            name="radioStatus" 
            [(ngModel)]="data.item.substitude"
        ></p-radioButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show us your code if you want us to help you. Without it, it's hard to know what's the issue.

Comment: You could use QuerySelector or simply pass the reference of the radio group and its index to a function.

Comment: Show what you've achieved so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `[(ngModel)]` along with a variable that you want to assign the value.